# Changing root password in centos7 during initramfs

Tags: linux

After Changing root password in Linux ,I am not able to login in to system either as root not as normal user .

In  my initramfs screen , file available was autorelabel not .autrelabel .

Please help me in resolving the issue .

Regards

Sakshi